# Как тип decimal избавился от проблем типа double?

Tags: c#, decimal

Знаю что при использовании типа double при решении простых арифметических задач может возникать подобные ситуации что ответ равен например 1.500000000003. Как мне известно это обловлено тем что операции которые в десятичной системе исчисления не вызывают вопросов в двоичной могут приводить к подобным неточностям.

Прошу объяснить какие особенности реализации типа decimal помогли решить подобную проблему. Ведь процессор может оперировать только числами в двоичной системе выходит есть промежуточный механизм который позволяет избавиться от этой проблемы.

Comment: `это обловлено тем что операции которые в десятичной системе исчисления не вызывают вопросов в двоичной могут приводить к подобным неточностям` нет, не так.

Comment: Очевидно, что у разных типов числовых перменных, разные способы хранения данных в памяти. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types Читайте документацию, там всё написано.